# $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)$. Why?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

[image]

I can't imagine how the third axiom is intuitive.
Let's even say $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)$. When I think about this affirmation I imagine the following Venn's diagram

[image]

or the classic example of throwing a dart to a target, where the target is divided in smaller cirles with different scores. I think about this examples in terms of the area because I believe it is simple and very visual. Beyond this visual concept, I can't explain why this is true.I would like a different idea apart from this one connected with geometry, because I believe it loses its meaning. I also know that axioms are supposed to be statments to be accepted as true, but I would like some reasoning. If can't explain $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)$ imagine taking a countable set like this $A_1,A_2,...$

If you have site or paper that mentions this please share it.

Comment: Think of $P(\cdot)$ as giving you the area of its argument (though in your writing it seems if $+$ is used inside $P$, it should be interpreted as union). Then $P(A+B)$, if $A,B$ are disjoint, is no different than the sum of the areas of the two circles individually. That is, if you let $C = A \cup B$ (a set defined to be those two, disjoint circles), then $P(C) = P(A) + P(B)$ clearly from your visual. But then $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$.

Comment: You don't get how the area of two circles is the sum of the two circle's areas?? If two people stand on a weighing machine together, wouldn't you expect the result to be the sum of their weights?!

Comment: You said "Behind this visual concept, I can't explain why this is true." To me, that sounds like you don't understand the visual concept. Perhaps you meant to say "**beyond** this visual concept" or something else?

Comment: If one set makes $a\%$ of the universe and another disjoint set makes $b\%$ of the universe then all together they form $(a+b)\%$ of the whole universe. Whether it is area in geometry, or probability, or counting, or ...

Comment: oh, I am sorry! that's it. I will fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it in terms of finite sets. Say, $A = \{1,2,3\}$ and $B = \{4,5,6\}$ and the Universe be integers $S = \{1,\ldots,9\}$. Then probability of events A and B are $p(A) = 1/3$, and $p(B)=1/3$ respectively. Now, let $C = A \cup B$, union choses unique values from both sets (as they all are unique in our case) $C=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. Therefore, $p(C)=p(A\cup B)=2/3=p(A)+p(B)$. This is because these are disjoint sets, that is no common elements between them. Now assume, both sets have a common element 7, in this case you see they are not disjoint sets anymore so the axiom won't hold. You can extend this to continuous events with some measure like length, area and so on but the basic idea would remain the same.

Answer (score 2):

You have a visitor that is supposed to arrive sometime this week. If $p$ is the chance that your visitor is going to arrive on Tuesday and $q$ is the chance that they will arrive on Wednesday doesn't it make sense to say that the chance they arrive on either one of these two days is $p+q$? The event $A$ is arriving on Tue, the event $B$ is arriving on Wed, and the event $A\cup B$ is arriving on one of these two days.

This only works because $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, that is, the visitor can't arrive on both Tuesday and Wednesday. If we change the example to make the events not disjoint, e.g. $A$ the event of it raining on Tue and $B$ being the event of it raining on Wed, then it is no longer correct that $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)$ because it might rain on both days. (e.g. if it's $0.9$ to rain on Tue and $0.9$ to rain on Wed it's surely not $1.8$ to rain on either one of those days-- probability can't be more than $1$).

Answer (score 0):

For two sets, the axiom states that $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B).$ The expression $A+B$ is not meaningful. This means that the area of the two circles together is the sum of the areas of each one separately.